# Conjugacy classes and normal form of $O_n$ and $U_n$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, linear-algebra, matrices, algebraic-groups, linear-groups

I'm interested in characterizing conjugacy classes inside $O_n$ and $U_n$ over local fields of positive characteristic ($\neq 2$). I need this for my research on representation theory of these groups.

Hopefully, I wish to have a decomposition into a direct sum of "simple" elements which one can describe explicitly, like in the case of $GL_n$, or some other "normal" form.

The best references I found are [this paper by Wall](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/S1446788700027622) and chapter E, IV of the book "Seminar on Algebraic Groups and Related Finite Groups", but it seems that with the characterization presented there it is hard to describe the conjugacy classes explicitly (e.g. in terms of a representative).

Is there a clearer way to do this?

Thank you very much

Comment: Since "local fields" are used in several senses in the literature (sometimes assumed to imply locally compact, sometimes not, sometimes Archimedean cases are included, often not...), it might be useful you define it.

Comment: @YCor - By local fields of positive characteristic I mean fields of the form $\mathbb{F}_q((t))$, with $\mathbb{F}_q$ being some finite field ($q$ is a power of a prime).

Comment: OK, these are exactly non-discrete locally compact fields of positive characteristic. By $O_n$, you mean the split form? or $O_n$ of any nondegenerate quadratic form?

Comment: @YCor - $O_n$ of any nondegenerate quadratic form (similarly for $U_n$). But if you have something for any particular case I would still be very interested in it.